# Mongoose add expires attribute for a specific field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have made a token based authentication system for my web application and I need to have an expiration date for the token field. The `user` model which keeps `token` is as follow:

```
module.exports = (function() {

  var userSchema = new Schema({
    phone: String,
    token: {
      value: { type: String, lowercase: true, trim: true }
    },
    verificationCode: Number,
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now() }
  });

  var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

  return User;

})();
```

I am wondering is there any way to have an expiration date attribute for the `token` field. Actually I want to have something like below in my code to check whether token is expired or not:

```
User.findOne({}, function( err, user ) {
  if (user.token.isExpired()) {
    // do something!
  }
});
```

Comment: why can't you put a expiration date (Date) isExpired (Boolean) fields in your token model and have a small job running which triggers every n'mins/sec/hours and update the isExpired to true if the current datetime is past the expireationdate set on the token.

Comment: You could also use a TTL Index on a token collection to automatically delete the token after a set amount of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for bring this up @dyouberg. Yes @sadrzadehsina You can use TTL indexes also but the only drawback here from your requirements perspective is once a document passes the TTL mongodb will remove the document from the collection. if you are ok to loose the documents probably TTL is the best option since everything will be taken care by mongodb itself. All you need to do is create an index on the collection.

if you your intention is to keep the documents then TTL may not be helpful however you can build a simple logic(i have it in the comment).

Comment: your solution in the comment is not that efficient. since I want my token to be expired after 10 minutes for example, then If I create a trigger to check it every 10 minutes too, consider a situation where the token is created at 11:00:00am and last trigger check was at 10:55:00am then the expiration date of then token will be 15 minutes not 10 minutes. It checks it at 11:05:00am, it is not expired, then it checks it again at 11:15:00am which is not what I want.

Comment: But TTL indexes are the solution in my case. since I can have another document to store all tokens and have a reference to in in the user document. then I can remove tokens and keeps users with a TTL index.