# Mongoose TTL for user saved tokens

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema, ttl

I have this User schema.

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
},
email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
},
password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
tokens: [{
    token: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    }
}], {timestamps: true});
```

I would like the token provided will **expiresAt** given time.

Any suggestions?

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40867987/mongoose-add-expires-attribute-for-a-specific-field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible with mongodb.
You can check this document: [MongoDb Index TTL](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/)

> TTL indexes are special single-field indexes that MongoDB can use to
> automatically remove documents from a collection after a certain
> amount of time or at a specific clock time. Data expiration is useful
> for certain types of information like machine generated event data,
> logs, and session information that only need to persist in a database
> for a finite amount of time.

You can create a new collection for user tokens and relate them on model. I think this could be a better practice. Then you can use ttl index on token collection